# Gauss Seidel - Finite Element Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, finite-element-method

I am solving an equation using finite element method, and for that I have to use Gauss Seidel to invert a matrix. 
In Gauss Seidel I am using a "while" which breaks if the absolute error reaches the error that I want but what happens is that the absolute error is always increasing along iterations...what could it be my error?

I think it is the initial guess for Gauss Seidel and so I tried some different initial guess than (0,...,0) such as (1, ..., 1) and (10, ..., 10).

Here is a part of my code:

```
double u_h[d], XO[d];

//initial guess
for(int i=0; i<d; i++) XO[i]=1.;

bool erro=false;
double erro_abs=100;
double erro_teorico=pow (10.0, -20.);

while (erro==false){

    for(int i=0; i<d; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<=i-1; j++) soma_j-=A[i][j]*u_h[j];

        for(int j=i+1; j<d; j++) soma_j-=A[i][j]*XO[j];

        u_h[i]=(soma_j+B[i])/(A[i][i]);
    }

    //error calculation:

        //1st i will calculate the largest absolute error of this iteration:
        double erro_abs_max=fabs(u_h[0]-XO[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<d; i++) {
        if (fabs(u_h[i]-XO[i])>erro_abs_max) erro_abs_max=fabs(u_h[i]-XO[i]);
    }
        erro_abs=erro_abs_max;

    if (erro_abs<erro_teorico) erro=true;

    for(int i=0; i<d; i++) XO[i]=u_h[i];

}
```

Comment: Try doing one iteration for a small example by hand so that you know what the result should be and then compare with output from you program. That is how I catch most of my bugs.

Comment: @CarlChristian, I had already tried and still dont know where is the error...I tried with one iteration.

Comment: In that case it is likely that your implementation is correct ;) It remains to verify that you matrix is, say, diagonally dominant, i.e. that you have a mathematical guarantee that the method should converge. In your position I would output the matrix, examine it manually or in MATLAB. Is you error growing at a fixed rate indicating systematic amplification as in the power method for eigenvalue computation?

Comment: Where do you initialize soma_j? It should be initialize in the for(int i=0; i<d; i++) loop so that it is initialized every time you calculate it, but it looks like you initialized it earlier without resting the value to 0 later.

Comment: Also the loops where you are computing soma_j don't look like they are stopping at the right indices.